# After AJAX call, newly loaded CSS selectors not available to jQuery.each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

**NOTE**
Though I'll defer to the wisdom of the herd, I don't agree that this is a duplicate (at least not as linked), and I was unable to find the answer to my problem on the linked page.

**Goal:**

1. Load HTML to element via ajax
2. Modify css of newly loaded elements based on information in data-attributes.

**Dilemma:**

After finishing (1) above, the newly loaded selectors don't seem to be available. I've been trying variations of `jQuery.on()` to try to get jQuery to register these newly added DOM elements. But I don't need event handling; I want to immediately alter the CSS of some of the newly arrived elements. I've tried a dozen variations on the below—most of which attempt to make the style changes *within* the `AJAX.success()` callback, rather than after it; this was just my last effort.

This *has* to be something simple, but I'm an hour in and I jsut can't see it...

Here's a sample of the loaded HTML:

```
<div class="jsonprinter-row indented-0 odd-row has-children" data-tab-offset="0" data-key-offset="0">
    <div class="jsonprinter-key">category</div>
    <div class="jsonprinter-list">
        <div class="jsonprinter-row indented-1 even-row" data-tab-offset="1" data-key-offset="10">
            <div class="jsonprinter-key">key</div>
            <div class="jsonprinter-value">val</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Aaaaand my JS:

```
var tab_size = 8;
var monospace_char = 3;

function updatePrintedRows(element) {
        var data = $(element).data();
        var width = data['tab-offset'] * tab_size + data['key-offset'] * monospace_char;
        $(element).css({"padding-left": toString(width)+"px"});
}
// note that I've tried both:
$(".jsonprinter-row").on("load", function() {
    updatePrintedRows(this);
});

// and also:
    $(document).on("load", ".jsonprinter-row", function() {
        updatePrintedRows(this);
    });
$("#printsheet").on('click', function() {
    $("#sheet-view").html( function() {
        var sheetData = // points to a Js object
        $.get("sheet_string.php", {sheet:sheetData}, function(data) {
            $("#sheet-view-content").html(data);
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: @Barmar So... if you read my question, I am already trying $jQuery.on() and it's not working, which is why I posted my question... I'm all for flagging duplicates, but might care to read the question fully first...

Comment: You're not using the delegation syntax of `on`. It should be `$(document).on("load", ".jsonprinter-row", function() { ...})`

Comment: That, meanwhile, is helpful—thanks. But—this doesn't change anything at all, for me... Any idea why? All my other JS is running fine (3000+ lines of custom code), so I am really stumped.

Comment: @Barmar No disrespect guy, but, the link you sent me to as a duplicate specifically is dealing with event bindings, which—barring the `.load()` event (which I currently can't seem to bind to)—is precisely what I don't need to address (or so I seem to think). But by marking this as a dup, you've also effectively preempted any chance of getting help. : /

Comment: OK, I've reopened it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If event delegation doesn't work for the `load` event, you need to call the function in the callback:

```
$("#printsheet").on('click', function() {
    $("#sheet-view").html( function() {
        var sheetData = // points to a Js object
        $.get("sheet_string.php", {sheet:sheetData}, function(data) {
            $("#sheet-view-content").html(data);
            $("#sheet-view-content .jsonprinter-row").each(function() {
                updatePrintedRows(this);
            });
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. This is a very subtle difference from the page you linked, works a charm.